# How to query data from eXist server XML database?

Tags: xml, exist-db

How to query results from an XML file stored in  eXist server? I am completely new to scripting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XQuery WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery) has a set of [examples for XQuery beginners](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery#Beginning_Examples) - this is a good starting point.